# Why does my C++ char array terminate early?

Tags: c++, arrays

The code below should read test string then open file and find similar string in the text file (that contains multiple lines) by reading first 8 chars to make sure code is on the correct line then read next 4 chars which could be different every time.

Code works fine for first 8 chars but last 4 chars it never reads

```
void test_value2()
{
    char charRead;
    unsigned char test2String[65] = "12345f67895f";
    unsigned char comparetest2String[65] = { 0 };
    unsigned int counter1 = 0, countChars = 0, countTestChars = 0, countChars2 = 0;
    std::fstream testResultsFile;
    testResultsFile.open("C:\\Tan\\test.txt", ios::in);
    do
    {
        counter1++; //count number of chars in test2String
    } while (test2String[counter1] != '\0');
    cout << "number of chars in test2String " << counter1 << endl;

    if (!testResultsFile)
    {
        cout << "File not found " << endl;
        cout << "Press ENTER to EXIT " << endl;
        getchar();
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        while (!testResultsFile.eof())
        {
            testResultsFile.get(charRead);  // Read char from the file
            countChars++;                   // count total character read for future comparison with countTestChars
            if (countTestChars == 8)
            {
                countChars2 = countChars;
                countTestChars++;
            }
            if ((charRead == test2String[countTestChars]) && (countTestChars < 9))
            {
                comparetest2String[countTestChars] = charRead;
                countTestChars++;
            }
            if ((countTestChars > 8) && (countTestChars < counter1)) // if at least first 8 chars matched, keep reading string
            {
                cout << "trying to read again" << endl;
                comparetest2String[countTestChars] = charRead;
                countTestChars++;
                if (countTestChars == counter1)
                {
                    cout << "done " << endl;
                    cout << comparetest2String << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `std::string` instead of `char` arrays?

Comment: You should **always** check for successful reading **after** having read! Also, using `std::istream::eof()` to control a loop is almost certainly wrong. The only real use of `eof()` is to check *after* detecting an error whether the error is due to having reached the end of the file. You should just use `while (testResultsFile.get(charRead)) { ... }`

Comment: You are zero-initializing the character array and skipping index 8, so the length of the character array appears to be 8. The other characters are being read and stored in the array, but they are after the null character.

Comment: The title is unclear, it's better to describe your specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

The logic error is in the following block:

```
if (countTestChars == counter1)
{
   cout << "done " << endl;
   cout << comparetest2String << endl;

   // This line here causes the code to break 
   // out of the while loop after 8 characters are read.
   break;
}
```

**Update**

On further examination of the code, the problem seems to be in the following block.

```
     if (countTestChars == 8)
     {
        countChars2 = countChars;

        // This line is the culprit. You end up skipping an index.
        // Since comparetest2String is zero initialized, you don't
        // rest of comparetest2String when you print it.
        countTestChars++;
     }
```

Removing the above line fixes the problem.

See working code at http://ideone.com/b6ebWu.

Comment: All due respect, I'm not sure this is the problem. `counter1` is equal to the number of characters in the test string. If the test string provided in the source code is `12345f67895f`, then `counter1` will be equal to 12. Read the code posted in the problem again.

Comment: Although, the `break` will break out of the loop after the first match. OP is trying to read multiple lines, so that isn't going to work.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I was able to fix it. I have a question: when I used "while (testResultsFile.get(charRead))" instead of "while (!testResultsFile.eof())", I could read only 5 characters. I am not sure why. I am not sure where to enter new code in case somebody want to see it because there is not enough room to enter the code here.

Comment: @StraightshooterStraightshoote, it will be better to post that as a different question.

Comment: The ideone code is better, but it doesn't read multiple lines.

Comment: @Derek, true. It wasn't clear to me what the OP wanted to do with multiple matching lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your indexing logic is off so you are skipping index 8. This is particularly problematic because you are zero-initializing the character array. This means that any gaps in the array will be treated like terminating characters and the length of the character array will appear to be 8. The other characters are being read and stored in the array, but they are after the null character. The logic is a little off, so the last 'f' isn't read so far as I can tell.

Your array `comparetest2String` ends up looking like this:

```
[1][2][3][4][5][f][6][7][\0][8][9][5]
```

So when you print that, you get:

```
12345f67
```

Notice that the other characters are read and stored in the array (minus the last 'f'), but the string is terminated by the `'\0'`, so the trailing characters are not printed.

Can you try subtracting 1 from the index `countTestChars` in the third `if` block? Does that help?

---

#### `std::string` based solution

What about if you change it to something like the following:

```
bool checkPrefix(const std::string& test, const std::string& input)
{
    const size_t PREFIX_LENGTH = 8;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < PREFIX_LENGTH; ++i)
    {
        if (input[i] != test[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void test_value1()
{
    const std::string TEST_STRING = "12345f67895f";   
    std::cout << "Number of chars in test string" << TEST_STRING.length() << std::endl;

    std::ifstream testFile("test.txt");
    if (!testFile)
    {
        std::cout << "File not found " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Press ENTER to EXIT " << std::endl;
        std::getchar();
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        std::string line;
        while (getline(testFile, line))
        {
            if (checkPrefix(TEST_STRING, line))
            {
                std::cout << "Found " << line << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This works for multiple input lines as stated by OP and doesn't contain any raw character arrays or error prone indices and counters!**

Input:

```
12345f67895f
BADPREFIX333
12345f67FDBC
```

Output:

```
12345f67895f
12345f67FDBC
```